# rpm build & deploy user and not as root

Tags: rpm

I'm new to RPM and was wondering whether it's possible to deploy a rpm package not as a root.
The reason behind this is that for our code releases we need to build a rpm, so though I build a rpm as myself, when I want to install it to test whether my package is fine, I need to have sudo access to rpm so that I can install it as root. The problem with this is that I cannot then delete the files/directories that were installed as part of this rpm, nor can I reinstall since I have only been given sudo rpm permission for "-ivh" option.

Answer (score 0):

No, not easily. Your best bet would be a chroot environment or something like a Docker/Moby container.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering whether it's possible to create a local repository (https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/1377211) and maybe install the rpms there? Is this something that is even worth exploring more? And, would this approach enable me to install rpms without root access since I'm targeting a local repository?

Comment: You seem to have your terminology confused. RPMs can be installed on a machine. When they are, that program / feature is now available. A repository is simply a place to keep them *to be installed* or accessed by others.

Comment: I just came across this - http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/rpm-installation-having-no-root-access-762363/. Using this approach, I think I can install a rpm locally and without needing to be the root. Am I right?

Comment: That's something covered by my "not easily" but yes, that should work.